# onLocationChanged() callback is never called until I turn on my device location tracker manually

Tags: android

I am developing an android app in which I need to track user's location when he/she opens the app. I am using the LocationService of GoogleApiClient. I use requsetLocationUpdates() of FusedLocationApi to update the location. But when I run my app, the onLocationChanged() callback is not called until I manually turn on my device location tracker.

Is there any way to update user's location without manually turning on device location tracker?

Comment: https://kjthumar.blogspot.de/2016/04/android-google-fusedlocationproviderapi.html?view=flipcard

check this link.

Comment: use NETWORK_PROVIDER if u do not want to turn ur Gps..

Comment: FInally turned to NETWORK_PROVIDER. This is simple. My app already needs internet. I found that GoogleApiClient LocationService has more accuracy. That's why I wanted to use it. Thank you for your valuable reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to track location on android you have to turn on tracker in settings. As far as I know there is no way to do it automatically.

So answering your question directly, there is no way to do it. Standard solution is to ask user to turn tracking on and open settings menu.

For example:

```
/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog
 * */
public void showSettingsAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    // Setting Icon to Dialog
    //alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.delete);

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

This is the link to the tutorial:
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/